# Basic Directions at a Point

Tags: linear-programming

Suppose we have
$$
\begin{equation}
  P=\begin{cases}
    x+y+z=2\\
    x,y,z \geq 0
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
For the resulting matrix $[\ 1 \ 1 \ 1 \ ]$ I know $n=3, m=1$.
If there is a BFS, $C = (0, 0 ,2)$. How do I find the basic directions at C?
I know there will be 2 basic directions, for $x$ and $y$ since those are non-basic varibles for C.

Comment: What is BFS? . .

Comment: @BenjaminWang Basic Feasible Solution